# Google apps script drive service download as function?

Tags: google-apps-script

Does google apps script have a function to 'download as' (.docx, plain text, .pdf, etc.)? I can't find any reference to one but wanted to check.

Comment: Google Apps Script hasn't any download method but you could do a "save as" by using Google Drive and/o Google Drive Advance Service, then use the HTML Service  to use client-side code to do the download.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at  the advanced [Google Drive Rest API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/export).  Specifically look at Drive.Files.export(fileId, mimeType).  Evidently, this only supports google docs